# Facebook SDK error on IOS App

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

Iam trying to add the FacebookSDK to an existing IOS app, followed the steps mentioned @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/
i.e., downloading the facebooksdk.pkg and dragging the files into Framework section of project Navigator

but when i run the app, the build fails.

> (null): error: /Volumes/E
>   Drive/anand/BrickLane/../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/Versions/A/Resources/FacebookSDKResources.bundle:
>   No such file or directory.

--
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess file is missing.

You can download latest Facebook package "FacebookSDK-3.1.1.pkg" from here

https://developers.facebook.com/ios/downloads/

Answer (score 11):

if you get this error after having upgraded to a newer version of Facebook SDK (f.e. 3.8), check the folder where the .bundle file should be: there should be a FacebookSDKResources.bundle.README file which tells that this file is no more needed, so you can safely remove its reference from the app project.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Deleted the "Resources" file that FB instructions had said to include and problem went away.