# The FacebookSDKResources.bundle is no longer required for your application

Tags: ios, facebook, xcode5, facebook-sdk-3.1

Trying to integrate my app with Facebook for login proposes, i've happened to notice the following log line:

```
2014-01-07 15:22:08.843 Nutrino[7457:70b] FBSDKLog: The FacebookSDKResources.bundle is no longer required for your application.  It can be removed.  After fixing this, you will need to Clean the project and then reset your simulator.
```

The problem is FacebookSDKResources.bundle is not even existing in my FacebookSDK directory. So basically this log message is redundant for me.
Normally i won't care much, but this log message is popping into my log console 3 times in a raw each time i'm instantiating FBLoginView.

Been looking around and saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19243435/1868924) which state that the guy is probably getting this error after having upgraded to a newer version of Facebook SDK. Unfortunately i'm not upgrading. I started a new project from scratch so i don't have any reference to safely remove from the app project.

Any suggestions? How can i get rid of these annoying log messages

Thanks in advance.

Gil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Ok - I've found out the source of the problem!!
I'm developing my app in xCode5.. Once in a while I open an older version of xCode with an older version of the app for some code references, so the problem happens when both projects are opened simultaneously. 
The `FacebookSDKResources.bundle` does exists on the older version of the project and this is the cause!

Hope it'll helps someone.

**original answer**

I'm not really sure if this is what solved it, since I left it as it was for a while and the next time I checked those log messages weren't there, but the only thing I do remember changing was the fact the I made my FBLoginView instance a singleton, so there was only one instance of it.

Worth the shot if anyone is dealing with the same issue.